# Letter Guessing Game in C

Tags: c

The error I got was that the number of game wasn't shown correctly. 
For example, I chose to play 2 games. I, then, tried to guess the first number correctly. The solution was shown and then jumped to the next game. However, the second game was shown as Game 3 instead of Game 2. 
I tried again. This time, I guessed the letter 1 time incorrectly and 1 time correctly. After the second guess, the game showed the solution and then stopped the game despite me choosing to play 2 games and only 1 game was played. 
The order of letters in LetterList file is 
d
B
G
w
Q
t
r
Y
u
X
So the first game starts with 'd' and then 'B' and then etc....
The error was shown as if the program itself got rid of even numbers. 
I don't know what was wrong with it.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXGUESSES 5


void LetterGuessRules();
void GuessTheLetter(char);
char GetTheGuess();
int CompareLetters(char, char);

int main()
{
    FILE *inPtr;
    int numGames, i = 0;
    char letter;

    //display the game rule
    LetterGuessRules();

    printf("\nHow many games do you want to play? (Max 10) >> ");
    scanf("%d", &numGames);
    printf("\n\n************************************************\n");
    inPtr = fopen("letterList.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < numGames; i++)
    {
        //get a solution letter from file - use fscanf
        fscanf(inPtr," %c", &letter);
        //change the solution to lowercase
        letter = tolower(letter);
        //print the solution back onto the screen to test

        //Close this when play the game to hide the foreseen solution
        printf("\nThe letter is %c\n", letter);   

        //Number of match
        printf("\t\tGame %d\n", i += 1);

        //call the GuessTheLetter function and pass it the solution
        GuessTheLetter(letter);
    }
    fclose(inPtr);
    return 0;
}

void GuessTheLetter(char letter)
{
    int win = 0;
    int numGuesses = 0;
    char myGuess;

    while (numGuesses < MAXGUESSES && win == 0)
    {
        //get a guess from the user  by calling the GetTheGuess function
        myGuess = GetTheGuess();

        //change the guess to lowercase
        myGuess = tolower(myGuess);

        //win = call the function to compare the guess with the solution
        win = CompareLetters(letter, myGuess);

        numGuesses++;//count the number of guesses so far

        //use conditions to let the user know if they won or lost the round of the game
        if (win == 0)
        {
            printf("\nOops its wrong.\n");
            if (myGuess < letter)
            {
                printf("Your guessed letter -%c- comes before the solution\n", myGuess);
                printf("Please guess again :)\n");
            }
            else if (myGuess > letter)
            {
                printf("Your guessed letter -%c- comes after the solution\n", myGuess);
                printf("Please guess again :)\n");
            }
            if (numGuesses == MAXGUESSES && win == 0)
                printf("Aw you have lost this game!");
                printf("\n");
        }
        else if (win == 1)
        {
            printf("\nYou have guessed it right!\n");
            printf("Wonderful! You ACE'd this match!\n");
            printf("\n");
            printf("**** If you play more than 1 game, new match will automatically start ****\n");
            printf("\tYou only need to keep guessing for the next letter\n");
            printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

char GetTheGuess()
{
    char myGuess;
    printf("\t_______________________");
    printf("\n\t|What's your guess? >> "); 
    scanf(" %c", &myGuess);

    return myGuess;
}

void LetterGuessRules()
{
    printf("\n*** Instruction: ");
    printf("\nYou will have 5 attempts to guess the right answer");
    printf("\nIf you guess it right, the game will end with your victory.");
    printf("\nOtherwise, you will have to guess again.");
    printf("\nPlease have fun!");
}

int CompareLetters(char letter, char myGuess)
{
    if (letter == myGuess)
    {   
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect chance to learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, to see what's happening and what the program is doing. You can also monitor variables and their values, and see how they change over the course of the program. Knowing how to use a debugger is an essential skill for any programmer, even hobbyist programmers.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I didnt really thnk of the debugger. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you increment `i` twice. First in the `for` loop, and again here:

```
    //Number of match
    printf("\t\tGame %d\n", i += 1);
```

This is probably because you got `Game 0` without it. The simple fix is to start the loop at 1 instead of 0.

Since `i` means something more than the "loop iterator" I'd call it something more descriptive like `gameNum`.

```
/* from 1 to numGames */
int gameNum;
for( gameNum = 1; gameNum <= numGames; gameNum++ ) {
    ...
}
```

Note that I check `gameNum <= numGames` rather than `gameNum < numGames` since we're now starting from 1.

Also you need to check if the file opened, otherwise it crashes if letterList.txt doesn't exist.

```
#include <errno.h>   /* for errno */
#include <string.h>  /* for strerror() */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for exit() */

inPtr = fopen("letterList.txt", "r");
if( inPtr == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open letterList.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Finally, I'd recommend against using `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` while learning C. Those security warnings are important.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll definitely try to fix it now. :)